# Exspected End of Statement vb UFT

Tags: vba, vbscript, hp-uft

I am not new to automation but am new to vb scripting and HP UFT. I keep getting errors in UFT saying (Expected end of statement) and (Expected identifier). My code is below. can you please help me?

```
Dim browserHome
Dim pageHome
Dim txtAnnualSalary
Dim txtCon401k

Set browserHome = Description.Create
browserHome("micclass").value = "Browser"
browserHome("name").value = "401K Calculator | How" //issue here


Set pageHome =Description.Create       //issue here
pageHome("micclass").value = "Page"   //issue here
pageHome("title").value = "401K Calculator | How" //issue here


Set txtAnnualSalary = Description.Create       //issue here
txtAnnualSalary("micclass").value = "WebEdit"   //issue here
txtAnnualSalary("name").value = "AnnualSalary"

Set txtCon401k = Description.Create
txtCon401k("micclass").value = "WebEdit"
txtCon401k("name").value = "Con401k"

Dim txtCon401k
Set txtCon401k = Description.Create
txtEmpMatch("micclass").value = "WebEdit"
txtEmpMatch("name").value = "EmpMatch"

SystemUtil.Run "iexplore.exe","http://www.401kcalculator.org/"
Browser(browserHome).Page(pageHome).WebEdit(txtAnnualSalary).Set "10000"
Browser(browserHome).Page(pageHome).WebEdit(txtCon401k).Set "30"
Browser(browserHome).Page(pageHome).WebEdit(txtEmpMatch).Set "30"
```

Comment: Why are you using `Description.Create` for each element...?

Comment: because that is what i was told to do by my automation team. We did a video call and he showed me his screen and it worked. they were in India. and they gave me a copy of there code to work from.

Comment: If there are 1000s of tests, I think you are compromising on performance.

Comment: Debug your code using `F11` and see which line is giving you error.

Comment: okay thats good to know. I never knew that before. what do you suggest?

Comment: If the objects are stable, I would suggest using a shared OR instead of identifying everything at run time.

Comment: the error is on line 30 browserHome("name").value = "401K Calculator | How". However i don't see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code Seems ok.But please check Whether Browser has a property called "name"  using Object Spy.If not you can't use that.

If Yes Then:

Also Can you try putting one Backspace the following line .

Instead of :

```
browserHome("name").value = "401K Calculator | How"
```

Try :

```
browserHome("name").value = "401K Calculator \| How"
```